# Hamburger menu, how to change color of cross

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

What should I do because I have a problem.
There was something wrong with X button on this menu I did It myself, and everything is correct but when I try to change color of X there is an error.
I would like to change the color of X to the black one.
[Theres a code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLvZmb)

```
<button class="js-menu menu" type="button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
</button>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>       
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the background of the class `.active:after` `.active:before`

```
.active & {
  background: none;
  &:after,
  &:before{
     background: red;
  }
```

http://codepen.io/pranesh-r/pen/gwkNwY

Answer (score 1):

You can change color with `.active` class

```
.active & {
    background: none;
    &:before,
    &:after {
       top: 0;
       background:red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `background color` to the psuedo selectors in your CSS. Add the following to your code

```
.active .bar::before, .active .bar::after {
    top: 0;
    background: #000;
}
```